# Texture showing differently on 2 Objects

Tags: texturing, materials, normal-map

Could someone tell me, why a texture shows differently on 2 Objects?

[image]

This is my material setup

[image]

[image]

Comment: Different UV layouts?

Comment: no, I only copied and mirrored the first object

Comment: Different normal direction? Try flipping the normals on one of the objects.

Comment: It gets better with flipping the normals, but they are still different

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=jL1dz9X4" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jL1dz9X4/)

Comment: oh sorry
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=JsmVjjrB" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JsmVjjrB/)

Comment: I tried flipping the Normals again and it worked, I dont know why not an Hour ago, but it workd, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal maps usually need to use *Non-Color* color space.
When set to sRGB they give unexpected results.

[image]

Comment: oh cool! Thanks :)

Comment: No problem :). Good luck with your project.